# Readcount in spring batch reader is less than source count

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am Using Spring batch withing spring boot.
reading a table from source and writing to destination.
i am populating three tables where the read-count for one of the table is less than Actual.

Say In source table there are 2656274 Rows but the read-count I am getting is readCount=2577203,  writeCount=2577203

other tables having 8 lacks records and 10 k records working fine

```
public class DxDatabaseItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<DxDataRead> {

    public  DxDatabaseItemReader(DxJobContext jobCntx) {
        synchronized (this){
        System.err.print("Into DxDatabaseItemReader");
        String[] dsParam =jobCntx.srcDbName.split("#");
        this.setDataSource(createOracleDataSource(dsParam[1],dsParam[2],dsParam[3]));
        this.setSql(createFetchQuery(jobCntx.srcFieldNames,jobCntx.srcTableName));//"SELECT SOEID, FST_NAM, LST_NAM FROM REF_PRSNL_MSTR");
        this.setFetchSize(0);
        this.setRowMapper((ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
            Map<String, String> fieldNameMap = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i=0;i<jobCntx.srcFieldNames.size();i++)
                fieldNameMap.put(getSrcFieldName(jobCntx.srcFieldNames, i), rs.getString(jobCntx.srcFieldNames.get(i)));
            DxDataRead dataRead = new DxDataRead();
            dataRead.setFieldNameMap(fieldNameMap);
            return dataRead; 

            });
        }
    }
```

Expected : it should read all the data and write

Comment: Can you share the entire SQL returned by this method? createFetchQuery(jobCntx.srcFieldNames,jobCntx.srcTableName)

Comment: Entire Sql is too long to post.
It got 79 columns names with table name

Comment: Ok, but I'm interested in the joins if there is any.

Comment: No Joins , simply I am reading from one table and similar table structure created in destination schema where copying a data

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT SOEID, FST_NAM, LST_NAM FROM REF_PRSNL_MSTR` returns `2656274` rows and not `2577203` ? Is there another job running concurrently and possibly removing data from that table? Otherwise, enable debug level in the logs and see if there are no errors while reading.

Comment: there was a job running concurrently creating same table with different schema name. Issue has been resolved now